# Ordenar pesquisa mysql por função

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um problema considerável:
- Quero listar uma pesquisa por uma função que faz uma contagem.
Eu quero que seja exibido pelo valor de notificações
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A contagem de notificações é feita a partir do seguinte código:

```
    function count_reports_where_id($conn,$id){
        //$cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT blogger_id FROM reports;";
        $cmd = "SELECT blogger_id FROM reports WHERE blogger_id = '$id'";
        $produtos = mysqli_query($conn,$cmd) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos);
        return $total;
    }
```

Minha estrutura MYSQL
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que lista:

```
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT blogger_id from reports ORDER BY ?????/;") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    echo 
    "<table border='1' padding='111'>
    <tr>
    <th>Blogger ID</th>
    <th>Notificações</th>
    <th>Opções</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['blogger_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . count_reports_where_id($conn, $row['blogger_id']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='admin_report.php?id=". $row['blogger_id'] ."'>Verificar</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Como ordenar a lista pela função count_reports_where_id? que necessita do blogger_id para contar?

Comment: Isso ficou bem confuso, espero que alguém entenda

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT blogger_id from reports order by $count_reports_where_id(bloggerid) ;") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Eu precisaria de algo desse tipo?

Comment: Pode tentar explicar de outra maneira? De que forma seria ordenada essa query?

Comment: O retorno dessa função é num_rows, então estaria ordenando por um valor inteiro, não consigo entender a lógica.

Comment: Você teria que ordenar o resultado da função onde ela é chamada. Mas acho que seria melhor adicionar o count no seu sql. Economizaria uma query e melhoraria a leitura. Vou elaborar uma resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme meu comentário, acredito que seria melhor você adaptar a primeira query pra trazer os valores contados e então ordenar por eles, assim, economizando várias queries desnecessárias e consequentemente economizando processamento, facilitando a leitura e aproveitando mais os recursos do mysql:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(blogger_id) as quantidade, blogger_id from reports group by blogger_id order by quantidade desc") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

echo 
"<table border='1' padding='111'>
<tr>
<th>Blogger ID</th>
<th>Notificações</th>
<th>Opções</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['blogger_id'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" .  $row['quantidade']  . "</td>";
 echo "<td><a href='admin_report.php?id=". $row['blogger_id'] ."'>Verificar</a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Não precisa mais da função count_reports_where_id**

> Mais informações:
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html
>   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
>   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp

Comment: Muito obrigado!